# How to add a timer?

Tags: ios, timer, touch, unity-game-engine

I have a working Unity script with multi-touch that will detect the touch, see if the touch has hit a collider (part of a gameObject), then checking to see if it is the right collider, and destroying it. Here is the working code:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour 

{

    void Update () // Updates every frame
    {
        if (Input.touchCount != 0) // Triggered by a touch
        {
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) // Triggered as many times as there are touches.
            {
                RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position), Vector2.zero);
                if (hit && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && hit.collider.gameObject.tag ==("Fish")) // Triggered if touch hits something, when touch just begins, and if the object hit was tagged as a "Fish"
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<FishScript>().TappedOut(); // Fish script activated
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the working code. Now I want to add a timer in there, and I want it to time the touch. I want to make it so if the player can tap, and move their finger over the fish and it will count, so long as the moved their finger over the fish in 1 second. Here is the script I wrote and need help with:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour 

{

    void Update () // Updates every frame
    {
        if (Input.touchCount != 0) // Triggered by a touch
        {
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) // Triggered as many times as there are touches.
            {
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    float touchTimer = Time.time;
                    int i = touch.fingerId;
                }
                RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position), Vector2.zero);
                if (hit && hit.collider.gameObject.tag ==("Fish")) // Triggered if touch hits something, when touch just begins, and if the object hit was tagged as a "Fish"
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<FishScript>().TappedOut(); // Fish script activated
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is all I have so far. I tried using a return statement, and that did not work in the Void Update() function. I tried making another function with a while loop that would wait until each frame finished before going through another loop. That did not work. Will this idea work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple timer in Unity. Put `CheckTimer()` on your `Update()` method.

```
private double counter = 0.000d;
public double time = 2.000d; // How many seconds you want your timer to run

void CheckTimer()
{
    counter+= Time.deltaTime;
    if (counter >= time)
    {
        // Time has passed
        counter = 0.000d;
        // Do stuff here..
    }
}
```

In your case, you may set a bool to true when your condition is met, then make it so that `CheckTimer()` only runs when the condition is true.

Comment: I'm not sure how this code will be handled. Before I begin testing, I'll tell you how this code may or may not work. So right off the bat, we define to private variables. These variables would need to be able to be duplicated per each touch. These codes would also need to stay consistent over each void update () frame. I think it may just be a bad idea to try and add a time factor inside a void update () function. What I may end up trying is a void update () that triggers another function when touch is detected. The other function will be IEnumerator, and have the rest of the code in it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this make the timer a global variable by instantiating it at the top and doing as follows

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour 

{
public float timer;
public float duration;

void Start(){
duration = 1; //you can set this in code or in your hierarchy in Unity 
}
    void Update () // Updates every frame
    {
        if (Input.touchCount != 0) // Triggered by a touch
        {

            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) // Triggered as many times as there are touches.
            {
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    timer = Time.time + duration;
                }
if(Time.time < timer){
                RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position), Vector2.zero);
                if (hit && hit.collider.gameObject.tag ==("Fish")) // Triggered if touch hits something, when touch just begins, and if the object hit was tagged as a "Fish"
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<FishScript>().TappedOut(); // Fish script activated
                }
            }
}
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have the rest of your code to ensure this works but the logic behind it does. You want to set your timer to the current time plus a given duration. If the current time is less than the timer you have set when the player does something, then you know they did their action before the time reached the timer. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not suppose to take up comment spaces by saying thanks, but thanks Jonnus. The only thing that baffles me now is how I didn't think of this sooner. Anyways, here is the take away code for anybody who needs help with a multi-touch script.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    Private float timer;      //  Control variable
    Public float duration;    //  How long you want your touch to be valid

Void Start ()
{
    duration = 1;             // Also adjustable in the interface
}

Void Update ()
{
    if (Input.touchCount != 0) // Triggered by a touch
    {
        Foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) // Triggered as many times as there are touches
        {
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                timer = Time.time + duration;
            }
            RaycastHit2D objectPlayerTouched = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position), Vector2.zero);
            // var objectPlayerTouched is the 2DCollider for whatever the player tapped on.
            if (objectPlayerTouched != null && Time.time < timer) // Triggered if player taps an object and time is still valid
            {
                objectPlayerTouched(destroy); // This means whatever object the player tapped is now destroyed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once again, a big thanks to Jonnus. I thought this would be a lot more complicated. Also, don't do what I did and forget to set the duration in the interface and end up spending 10 minutes looking for a problem... Trust me it's annoying.